# Image distortion on touch

Tags: android, opengl-es, distortion, android-gpuimageview

There is an app named Funny Face Effects on the play store.

I am trying to achieve the effect in which when a user moves the finger on image, pixels under the finger in certain radius shifts in that direction. It feels like moving a cloth with a finger or moving some thick paste with the finger. I could not find a proper name but I think it is called smudge/liquify.

After searching and trying I found that I can achieve this with GPUImage library.This library uses OpenGL fragment shader to apply some effect on image.

How can I achieve this effect without using the GPUImage library? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of libraries are there in the github. Search for it. Here is a nice one : https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to achieve first three filters from below application.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.warp